# SwiftMailer - how do I set the header to send out a 'Successful Mail Delivery Report'

Tags: php, email, swiftmailer, email-headers, receipt

I know I can use the following code to send a request a read receipt, but is it possible to automatically send out an 'successful mail delivery report' using the SwiftMailer library?

```
$mailer->setReadReceipt('joebloggs@email.com');
```

Is there a function built into SwiftMailer for sending out an automatic read receipt - note I am using the latest version of SwiftMailer (v5.x)

I'm not sure if this will require some implementation of X-Confirm-Reading-To: and Return-Receipt-To?

## UPDATE

In Thunderbird there is an option to enable 'Delivery Status Notification' - This when enabled will send an email stating an 'Successful Mail Delivery Report'. I want to have this option within SwiftMailer, does it do this?

Comment: Not sure I follow you... Swift Mailer is an SMTP client, not a server. It cannot receive email. When and how do you want it to send such report? Do you want to simulate Thunderbird's report on demand?

Comment: Thanks Alvaro I see what you mean now... it is the client so i'll need to basically do something that says if ($mailer->send == true) // the send out our own 'Successful Mail Delivery Report email
I'll update with an 'proper' answer shortly
+1 for pointing me in the right direction